# Decrypting binary file with asc private key in java

Tags: java, encryption, binary, rsa, private-key

Dears,

I have a **binary** file in .DAT format, and a private key in .asc format with the following format

```
-----BEGIN PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK----- 
Version: GnuPG v1

//key goes here
-----END PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
```

Tried using java security, and Bouncy Castle library with no hope.

If I used the following code to create a private key object

```
byte[] encoded = Base64.decodeBase64(privateKeyPEM);
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
RSAPrivateKey privKey = (RSAPrivateKey) kf.generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(encoded));
```

I got `InvalidKeyFormat exception`.
If I didn't use `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec` , I got a decrypted file with nothing readable.

Comment: A PGP private key is not in PKCS8 format, it's in PGP format. You should probably use a PGP/GPG library like Bouncycastle OpenPGP library.